# Umbraco XSLT RenderTemplate Woes

Tags: macros, umbraco

Needing a little guidance with XSLT and Umbraco. Fairly new to XSLT but I think I understand the concepts. Right on one page I have two columns, each with their own separate **pickable** content. This is done via the standard content picker property (one for each column). The issue is that I need to be able to have two different templates on the page. So in essence the page navigated two which has the columns has to render two of it's child items in its own page.

I have this working with one column using a generic XSLT which I found that basically just renders what ever child item it finds, but I want it to render what ever one the user picked.

I know the Content Picker returns the XML Node ID of the page and that can be used with the Render Template function to display it (I have an example of that), but when it comes to adding in my own properties and then passing them to the RenderTemplate function I get lost. New to this XSLT :).

So far I have...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [ <!ENTITY nbsp "&#x00A0;"> ]>
       <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
       xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
     xmlns:umbraco.library="urn:umbraco.library"
     xmlns:Exslt.ExsltCommon="urn:Exslt.ExsltCommon"
     xmlns:Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes="urn:Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes"
     xmlns:Exslt.ExsltMath="urn:Exslt.ExsltMath"
     xmlns:Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions="urn:Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions"
     xmlns:Exslt.ExsltStrings="urn:Exslt.ExsltStrings"
     xmlns:Exslt.ExsltSets="urn:Exslt.ExsltSets">
   <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:param name="currentPage"/>
<xsl:variable name="nodeID" select="data[@alias='leftColumn']"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:RenderTemplate($nodeID)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any one know why this doesn't work and how to do what I'm after? The above gives a value was either too large or too small error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have two problems here ...

**Calling RenderTemplate()**

`RenderTemplate` actually requires two arguments when using an alternative template, the first being the content node ID, and the second being the chosen template you want applied.

```xml
<xsl:value-of 
    select="umbraco.library:RenderTemplate($nodeID, $templateID)" 
    disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```

See the following link for more information : http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/umbracolibrary/rendertemplate

**Too large or too small error**

This one is simple to fix by putting an if-empty statement around the the code in question.

```xml
<xsl:if test="$nodeID != ''">
    <xsl:value-of 
        select="umbraco.library:RenderTemplate($nodeID, $templateID)" 
        disable-output-escaping="yes" />
</xsl:if>
```

The XSLT parser likes to assume certain values are null, when in reality they aren't. Another way to get by this is to check the `Skip Errors` checkbox when saving, but this makes debugging actual erroneous code a bit of a pain.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've looked round and from what I could see you could pass in a nodeID on it's own. I will give it a test with a templateID but I don't think thats the error. I dug around a little more and it seems that no matter what the nodeID variable never gets any data in it. I've printed the content Picker out on the page in the template designer with '<umbraco:Item field="leftColumn" runat="server" />' and that prints out the right data but using it in the XLST it never gets the data.

Comment: What version of Umbraco are you using?

Comment: umbraco v 4.7.1 (Assembly version: 1.0.4281.20201)

You can see the site - http://priority.wireddotnet.co.uk/

Comment: Ahh, I think I know what it is. From 4.5 onwards, Umbraco updated their XML schema that the XSLTs run from. So a lot of the documentation online is grossly out of date. Try modifying your variable declaration for `nodeID` to the following: `<xsl:variable name="nodeID" select="$currentPage/leftColumn" />`. Here's some more info about it at [http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/xslt/45-xml-schema](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/xslt/45-xml-schema). Also, If you ever need to figure out some XPATH by checking the raw XML, look into the `~/App_Data/Umbraco.config` file.

Comment: Thanks, and no worries. And you're most likely right about the single-arugment RenderTemplate call. I guess it'd use the default template assigned to the document type. I personally haven't used it often enough to say otherwise.